# Activity foreground/background nomenclature

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

When a view goes from *visible* to *gone* one can say that the view's **visibility** changed.

When an activity goes from *background* to *foreground* one can say that the activity **??*what*??** changed?

What is that word that can describe that?

Comment: activity was resumed

Comment: activity state changed.

Comment: "When an activity goes from background to foreground" -- what exactly do you mean by this? By "background", do you mean that the activity is no longer receiving user input because it is obscured? Do you mean that the activity is no longer receiving user input because the user tapped on some other window in a multi-window scenario? Do you mean that the activity is no longer visible? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare 
Going to background in the sense of when another app/another activity (even a translucent one) appears at front or when the screen is locked. But not when a popup/dialog or a window (in a multi window scenario) takes focus. 
By “foreground” I mean it is the current activity running in the screen (or at least on its half screen on the multi window scenario).

Comment: I cannot think of a simple term for what you are seeking, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The Activity is resumed or brought from the [*Activity stack*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

When an activity goes from background to foreground

**we can say it "Activity is Resumed"**

OR

**we can say it "Activity is running" or "Activity is foregrounded"**